# Mimic batch file with C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs the four commands

```
vsinstr -coverage hello.exe
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
hello
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

How can I use C# to run the four commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the commands using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

**Example**

Using the override `Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments)`

```
Process.Start("vsinstr", "-coverage hello.exe");
Process.Start("vsperfcmd", "/start:coverage /output:run.coverage");
Process.Start("hello");
Process.Start("vsperfcmd", "/shutdown");
```

Comment: Bah! You beat me to it! :) Edited your answer with an example.

Comment: @Filip: Well you were faster with the example than me, were just about to post some in (I forgot what language it was and wrote it in VB and then took a little while to load the online converter etc). Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

Add these command to a batch file and use the below code to run it

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
 System.Diagnostics.Process batchExecute;

 startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("batchFilePath");
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 startInfo.Verb = "runas";

 batchExecute = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 batchExecute.StartInfo = startInfo;

 batchExecute.Start();

 batchExecute.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Setting `Verb` to `"runas"` will run the process elevated, including any necessary UAC prompts. If you don't need to elevate, don't set this property (or set it to `"open"`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a batch file, why not run it from C# instead of running the commands in it from C#? For example:[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326950%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)